# aligning form fields when they are displayed as fractions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to figure out how to display the following code properly aligned:

```
 <label>N = A</label>
 <input type="number" id="A" name="" style="width:10%;">
 <label style="width:2em; height:4em;">+</label>
 <label style="width:2em; height:4em;">&#40;</label>
 <label>B</label>
 <input type="number" id="B" style="width:10%;" min="0" max="16777215">
 <label style="width:2em; height:4em;">+</label>
 <label>C</label>
 <input type="number" id="C" style="width:10%;" min="0" max="16383">
 <label style="width:2em; height:4em;">&#47;</label>
 <label for="D">D</label>
 <input type="number" id="D" name="" style="width:10%;" min="2" max="16383">
 <label style="width:2em; height:4em;">&#41;&nbsp&#47;&nbsp16,777,216&nbsp&nbsp</label>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something that looks like:

```
              C
         B + ---
              D
N = A + ----------
        16,777,216
```

For me it doesn't really matter how it is done, with `JavaScript`, `JQuery` or `CSS`. Unfortunately my knowledge of all of these three subjects is very limited. I tried looking online and found a few things, but none of them tell me how to align everything. Only the fraction portion is aligned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using table for this?

Comment: @claudios Thanks. It worked. Can you post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do many options to achieve the desired output like [CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) but the easiest way is to do this is using `html table`.